# hvplot / holoviews (bokeh) timedelta axis with negative values formatter

Tags: python, bokeh, timedelta, holoviews, hvplot

#### Issue:

I am trying to plot data with a pandas time delta index with ***negative* time delta** values on the x-axis using hvplot or holoviews (bokeh backend).

The labels are just integers, and seem to be in milliseconds.
I want them to be formatted in a friendlier format such as HH:MM:SS

#### EXAMPLE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hvplot.pandas

x = pd.timedelta_range(start=0, freq='S', periods=11) - pd.Timedelta('5S')
y = np.arange(len(x))
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y}, index=x)
df.hvplot.line(rot=20)
```

**Output:**
[image]
I expected the x axis to be -00:00:04 -00:00:04 00:00:00 00:00:02 00:00:04
or at least in seconds, this seems to be milliseconds.

#### What I tried

using the df create above:

```
from bokeh.models.formatters import NumeralTickFormatter
df.hvplot.line(xformatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format="00:00:00"), rot=20)
```

**Output:**
[image]
Idk what happened here with the xlabels but they dont really make any sense.

**Using DatetimeTickFormatter:**

```
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
df.hvplot.line(rot=20, xformatter=DatetimeTickFormatter())
```

[image]

Does not work unfortunatelt: No negative values: - 00:00:02 becomes 58s

Comment: You probably want `DatetimeTickFormatter` which will format Bokeh's underlying milliseconds-since-epoch datetime values, not `NumeralTickFormatter`

Comment: Thank you, but DatetimeTickFormatter does not handle negative values: You get 59:00 instead of -1:00

Comment: Well, these aren't actually datetime values, they are merely relative time durations, so perhaps not surprising. Your best bet is probably a line or two of JS in a [`FuncTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.3/docs/user_guide/styling.html#functickformatter), which will let you format the millisecond values however you like. Note that in Bokeh 3.0 it will be renamed `CustomJSTickFormatter` to bring APIs into consistency.

Comment: thanks, yes that would more be in the direction of the solution i posted below, where you basically parse the ticks right? I am not great with JavaScript but what i found (https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-convert-milliseconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds) looks pretty similar I think, or is there faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it is not pretty but it works
(Using the earlier created dataframe):

```
def timedelta_formatter(x):
    x/=1000                       # ms -> seconds

    # extract seconds, minutes, hours, days from time
    m, s = divmod(abs(x), 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    d, h = divmod(h, 24)
    
    # create output string with time format
    out = f"{d}d. {h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}"

    if x < 0:
        # add - if negative value
        return "- " + out
    else:
        return out
df.hvplot.line(xformatter=timedelta_formatter, rot=20)
```

**Output:**
[image]

This looks better!

Lets try it with a timedelta range in days:

```
x = pd.timedelta_range(start=0, freq='D', periods=11) - pd.Timedelta('5D')
y = np.arange(len(x))
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y}, index=x)
df.hvplot.line(xformatter=timedelta_formatter, rot=20)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Works too

I still think this is not the most elegant solution,
so open to hear better solutions

Comment: does this also work with the plotly backend?